# Property in array object returning wrong value when getting values from another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I was doing a project for the online curriculum "The Odin Project", and I am doing the calculator project. I'm trying to get a list of simple equations that come from the longer equation, coming from the user's input, and then separate the equations by the first number, the operator, and the second number. The problem is, that the value for the first number is returning the actual value, added to a seemingly random value. Here's an example for my code:

```
function operate(){
//Declare an array that is equal to the return value of getEquation()
let equations = getEquation();
console.log(equations);
//For each item in the equations array, check what the operator is and if it's '*' or '/', call the appropriate function on the numbers in the array. Make the outputValue the answer, and make num1 of the next equation the answer of the previous equation
let answer = null;
for(let i=0; i<equations.length; i++){
    //If the previous answer isn't null, make that the value of num1
    if(answer != null){
        equations[i].num1 = answer;
    }
    switch(equations[i].operator){
        case '*': answer = multiply(equations[i].num1, equations[i].num2)
        console.log(answer);
        finalizeEquation(answer);
        break;
        case '/': answer = divide(equations[i].num1, equations[i].num2)
        finalizeEquation()
        break;
    }
}
//Then, do the same thing again but check if the operator is '+' or '-'
for(let i=0; i<equations.length; i++){
    //If the previous answer isn't null, make that the value of num1
    if(answer != null){
        equations[i].num1 = answer;
    }
    switch(equations[i].operator){
        case '+': answer = add(equations[i].num1, equations[i].num2)
        finalizeEquation()
        break;
        case '/': answer = subtract(equations[i].num1, equations[i].num2)
        finalizeEquation()
        break;
    }
}
answer = null;

//Declare getEquation(), which returns an array of objects with operator, num1, and num2 as properties
function getEquation(){
    console.log(inputArray)
    //Declare equations array
    const equations = [];
    for(let i=0; i<inputArray.length; i++){
        //Check if the current index in the array is an operator
        if(isOperator(inputArray[i])){
            console.log(inputArray[i-1]);
            //Push an object with the number before the operator as "num1", the operator as "operator", and the number after the operator as "num2"
            equations.push({
                num1: parseFloat(inputArray[i-1]),
                operator: inputArray[i],
                num2: parseFloat(inputArray[i+1])
            })
        }
    }
    //Return the equations array
    return equations;
}
```

The *console.log(equations)* is supposed to show me the value for the equations. I've been testing this with the equation "1 + 3 * 6", and the equations array was returning something completely different. Here's an example, tested with the aforementioned equation: [The message logged into the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1OhC.png)

The message returns *Array [ {…}, {…} ]
​
0: Object { num1: 18, operator: "+", num2: 3 }
​
1: Object { num1: 21, operator: "*", num2: 6 }
​
length: 2*

I also console.logged the value being passed into num1 right before it was passed, and it returned the correct value, so I think it must've been a problem with the object, but I've been looking for the solution for hours and I can't find it. I'm a beginner, so please go easy on me! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After looking into the codebase, I found why you are getting this issue.
Let's have a look at your output and code.

First you get equations as `[{ num1: 1, operator: "+", num2: 3 }, {num1: 3, operator: "*", num2: 6 }​]` and answer as null.

---

Now, in first for loop, since the **answer** is null, you won't update any equation. Also, you would perform the multiply operation and store the value 18 (3 * 6) in answer.

So, after first for loop we have equations as `[{ num1: 1, operator: "+", num2: 3 }, {num1: 3, operator: "*", num2: 6 }​]` and answer as 18.

---

Now, in second loop, we have non-null answer value (i.e. 18). So you are assigning this answer value to the num1 of first equation, so `{ num1: 1, operator: "+", num2: 3 }` object value is updated to `{ num1: 18, operator: "+", num2: 3 }`.
Also, you would be performing the addition operation and store 21 (18 + 3) it in the **answer** variable.

But, since there are more element in the array, we will go to the next element, which is `{num1: 3, operator: "*", num2: 6 }`. And since the answer is non-null value (21), the num1 of this object would be updated and the object becomes `{num1: 21, operator: "*", num2: 6 }`.

---

Hence after executing the function you will get `[{ num1: 18, operator: "+", num2: 3 }, {num1: 21, operator: "*", num2: 6 }]`, with answer as 21.

Now, how to fix this, the problem with your approach is you have separated the equation properly, but you are not aware which part of equation would be solved/computed first. So, till you are using this 2 for-loops, you won't be able to achive the correct result.

To solve this question, you either have to use `Tree` or `Stack` data structure. You can refer https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/expression-tree/ for same.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I'll do my research on those data structures and I'll look out for this next time. Thank you again!